# ASP.NET create printable forms

Tags: asp.net

i have a number of word documents (forms) that i need to publish it as interactive web form(no database connection just form with text entries fields) on the site to be printable, is there a way to publish them with the least effort.

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. create your web pages with the desired minimal design that you need (html tables and so)
2. in the parts that you need to show your word documents content add placeholders, for example in your aspx page add placeholder %address% and then replace this placeholder in the address content from the word document.
3. after that you will have your web page has all your word doc content and you can print from there.